# how to write if Fraction sum equal to 1?

Tags: java

Need to write code for this requirement.
Get 6 number inputs from user ( a b c d e f) and check (if a/b + c/d + e/f) =1.

If it does,print yes if not will print no.Can only use int variable.

i started to try

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    int a = myScanner.nextInt() ;
    int b = myScanner.nextInt() ;
    int c = myScanner.nextInt() ;
    int d = myScanner.nextInt() ;
    int e = myScanner.nextInt() ;
    int f = myScanner.nextInt() ;
    int rbd = b%d ;


    if (rbd!=0) {
        b=d ;
        d=rbd ;
        rbd= b%d ;
    }
    int rbdf = d&f ;
    if (rbdf != 0 ) {
        d=f ;
        f=rbdf ;
        rbdf = d%f ;
    }

    if ((a+c+e) % f ==0) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    } else { System.out.println("no");
    } }}
```

Comment: You already wrote what you need to do `if (a/b + c/d + e/f) =1` ... what is your actual issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you just check for `a*c*e*3 == b*d*f`?

Comment: why `b%d`, `d&f`, `d%f`, `(a+c+e) % f` ??? does not resemble what is asked for

Comment: @SeverityOne how that?  try with `a=1, b=1, c=-1, d=1, e=1, f=1` it is more like `a*d*f+b*c*f+b*d*e == b*d*f`

Comment: @Carlos Neuberger 1/1 + 1/1 + 1/1 = 3, and that's not what's being asked.

Comment: @Elad you can check if (adf+cbf+ebd==bdf).

Comment: @SeverityOne `1/1 + -1/1 + 1/1 == 1 - 1 + 1 == 1` since `c=-1` (negative) but it does not matter, `a/b + c/d` is **not** `(a+c)/(b+d)` !

Comment: @Carlos Neuberger You're right, it should be `(a+c+e)*3 == b+d+f`. Too long ago that I went to school...

Comment: @SeverityOne still wrong... [:-| try it with `a=1, b=1, c=e=0, d=f=1` (kind of obvious)

Comment: Besides the solution @uneq95 suggested, check that b, d and f != 0.

Comment: @RobertKock yes, yes! otherwise it wont be divisible.

Comment: The fractions a/b, c/d and e/f can lead to any decimal. If you need to make sure that the whole expression evaluates to a whole number 1, you need to make a common denominator and then check the condition.

Comment: @ SeverityOne  (a+c+e)*3 == b+d+f still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

So, formalizing the solution of @uneq95, together with my previous comment, you get:

```
if ((b == 0) || (d == 0) || (f == 0))
  System.out.println("no");
else if (((a*d*f) + (c*b*f) + (e*b*d)) == (b*d*f))
  System.out.println("yes");
else
  System.out.println("no");
```